# trying to make a value true on click with an if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change between colors on click in jquery. According to the picture below I have the default value 
[image]

and then in this image when I click on the input box and then back on a button the background color stays on the input box rather than dissappears when any other button is clicked.
[image]
[image]

i'd like the background color to disappear when any of the buttons are clicked.

here is my jquery:

```
    $("#donation-amount").click(function() {

         if ($(this).hasClass('inpt-first')) {
             $(this).css("background-color", "#c97e06");
             $("#default").removeClass('active');
             $("#btn2").removeClass('active');
             $("#btn3").removeClass('active');
         } 

        else{
            $(this).removeAttr("background-color") 
            $("#default").addClass('active');   
        }

    });
```

and here is my html:

```
   <div class="choose-pricing">
          <div class="btn-group">
          <div class="buttons">
            <button type="button" id="default" class="btn btn-default selectvalue hover-color active" value="50">50</button>
            <button type="button" id="btn2" class="btn btn-default selectvalue hover-color" value="100">100</button>
            <button type="button" id="btn3" class="btn btn-default selectvalue hover-color" value="150">150</button>
            <input type="Custom" name="donation-amount" class="inpt-first form-control" id="donation-amount" onclick="if(this.defaultValue == this.value) this.value = ''" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value = this.defaultValue" value="Custom">
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="donation-amount-value" id="donation-amount-value">
          </div>
          <div class="money-donate">
            <div class="display-amount" id="display-amount">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
```

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you provide the names of your attributes or your HTML?

Comment: Yes I already did that

Comment: @avasssso, if you want the back groud color to remove if you click on other buttons, you should create event handlers for other buttons and add code for that. here you have added click event only for #donation-amount

Comment: I have event handlers for the other buttons. I am able to have the colors change on the buttons just fine but for some reason I can't get it to change for the input box

Comment: Can you show the code for other event handlers,may be your issues exists in that code.

Comment: Just figured it out! I needed to add '  $('#donation-amount').css("background-color","") ' to my button event handlers!

Comment: Glad your issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(this).css("background-color", "")
```

Instead of this

```
$(this).removeAttr("background-color")
```

You cannot remove the `background-color` like this as it is not an attribute.

Comment: Nope. Still the same issue.

Comment: You can't remove an backgroun-color attribute because it does'nt exists an attribute background-color.

Comment: @FernandoUrban, did you check my answer, that is exactly what I have said there. Are you the down voter?

Comment: It was a mistake, I was scrolling down the page and click under the wrong site. The vote down was remove, I'm only want to comment your answer. Greetings. My comment was for @avasssso

Answer (score 0):

**On click of button you should remove the class active from the donation-amount**

what you have written will only work as toggle on the custom button only. Its not interacting with rest of the buttons.

Flow should be to remove class from custom button if any button is hit and if custom button is hit remove class from any of button.

```
 $(".selectvalue").each(function(){

    $(this).click(function(){
         $("#donation-amount").removeClass('active');
    })

    });

    $("#donation").click(function(){
        $(".selectvalue").removeClass('active');

    })
```

Comment: check my answer now @avasssso

Answer (score 0):

Is this the functionality you are looking for? Also added in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4rn73rv3/)

Instead of background color, just use the `.active` class

```js
    
  $('#donation-amount,#default, #btn2, #btn3').click(function(event) {
    
    //add any other checks you want here
    $("#default").removeClass('active');
    $("#btn2").removeClass('active');
    $("#btn3").removeClass('active');
    $("#donation-amount").removeClass('active');
    $(event.target).addClass('active');
  });
```

```css
.active{
  background-color:#c97e06;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="choose-pricing">
          <div class="btn-group">
          <div class="buttons">
            <button type="button" id="default" class="btn btn-default selectvalue hover-color active" value="50">50</button>
            <button type="button" id="btn2" class="btn btn-default selectvalue hover-color" value="100">100</button>
            <button type="button" id="btn3" class="btn btn-default selectvalue hover-color" value="150">150</button>
            <input type="Custom" name="donation-amount" class="inpt-first form-control" id="donation-amount" value="Custom">
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="donation-amount-value" id="donation-amount-value">
          </div>
          <div class="money-donate">
            <div class="display-amount" id="display-amount">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought this code satisfied your requirement.
if your problem is not solve then write comment in explain then I can do it.
Please vote for me.

```
$("#donation-amount").click(function() {

            if ($(this).hasClass('inpt-first')) {
                console.log("hello");
                $(this).css("background-color", "#c97e06");
                $("#default").removeClass('active');
                $("#btn2").removeClass('active');
                $("#btn3").removeClass('active');
            } 
        });
        $("body").on("click","#default,#btn2, #btn3",function(){
            //console.log($(this));
              $("#donation-amount").css("background-color","rgb(255,255,255)");
                //$("#default").addClass('active');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems a bit complicated the way you have it.  This is a classic "choice highlight" scenario and is easily handled with a simple `$(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');` to set and remove the active highlight.

I also took the liberty of making the assumption you want some CUSTOM amount so I added a simple input for that to use with the CUSTOM button.  I also simplified the custom button by using the data attribute and removed the code from that as frankly it seemed weird to have in there.

HTML with some adjustments:

```
<div class="choose-pricing">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <div class="buttons">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default selectvalue hover-color choice default active " value="50">50</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default selectvalue hover-color choice" value="100">100</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default selectvalue hover-color choice" value="150">150</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default selectvalue hover-color choice" value="" id="donation-amount" data-defaultvalue="57">Custom</button>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="donation-amount-value" id="donation-amount-value">
  </div>
  <div class="money-donate">
    <div class="display-amount" id="display-amount">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">Custom Amount
  <input id="customamount" type="text" value="67" />
</div>
```

Code that sets the color using an `active` class and sets the custom amount in the hidden field (or default if it has none)

```
$(".choice").on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).is("#donation-amount")) {
    var mydefault = $(this).data("defaultvalue");
    // use custom amount if it has one, otherwise use this custom default
    this.value = $('#customamount').val() || mydefault;
  }
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  $('#donation-amount-value').val(this.value);
  $('#display-amount').text('$'+this.value);
});
```

CSS:

```
.active {
  background-color: #c97e06;
}
```

You can play around with it here: https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/6Lj62ngs/1/